# Dead C variables

Tags: c, callstack

I'm working on some private code that I can't show, but I've made some sample code to describe my issue:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint32_t (*FuncPtr)(char *s, uint32_t n);

uint32_t doSomething(char *s, uint32_t n){ 
    printf("n is %d in doSomething\n", n);
    printf("s is '%s' in doSomething\n\n", s);
    return 0;

}

uint32_t func1(char *s, uint32_t n){
    printf("n is %d in func1\n", n);
    printf("s is '%s' in func1\n\n", s);
    return doSomething(s, n);
}

uint32_t func2(char *s, uint32_t n){
    printf("n is %d in func2\n", n);
    printf("s is '%s' in func2\n\n", s);
    return doSomething(s, n);
}

uint32_t func3(char *s, uint32_t n){
    printf("n is %d in func3\n", n);
    printf("s is '%s' in func3\n\n", s);
    return doSomething(s, n);
}

void perform(FuncPtr fp, char *s, uint32_t n){
    printf("fp is location in %p\n", fp);
    printf("n is %d in perform\n", n);
    printf("s is '%s' in perform\n\n", s);
    fp(s, n);
}

int main(void) {

    srand(time(NULL));
    uint32_t r = (uint32_t)(rand() % 3 + 1);
    uint32_t n = (uint32_t)(rand() %100);
    char *s = "some string here";

    printf("r is %d\n", r);
    printf("n is %d in main\n", n);
    printf("s is '%s' in main\n\n", s);

    switch(r)
    {
        case 1:
            perform(func1, s, n);
            break;
        case 2:
            perform(func2, s, n);
            break;
        case 3:
            perform(func3, s, n);
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the call stack:

```
 0  func1(s=0x9abcdef0, n=0 << Dead >>) [..\main.c:9,1]
 1  perform(fp=0x12345678, s=0x9abcdef0, n=42)  [..\main.c:21,1]
 2  main()  [..\main.c:25,10]
```

As you can see on the top, the `n` that is passed into `func1` is `<< dead >>` and does not match the value in `perform` even though the `s` pointer always holds on to the same address. Why is this happening? I haven't found a helpful description of what a dead variable is anywhere. Is there any fix I can make to this code or does this involve more compiler/memory issues that I can't implement here?

Comment: Is the output from `printf` correct, though?

Comment: A *dead variable* is one that is not used in its context.  So a reasonably good compiler will not do anything to make its value accessible (like moving it to a register).  It might even optimize away all of its handling.

Comment: @wallyk Any idea how that applies in this case? `func1()` does use `n` in both the `printf()` and when calling `doSomething()`. I have a feeling it's due to tail-call optimization, so it's reusing its parameter block when it makes this call.

Comment: Did you disable optimization when you compiled?  There are all kinds of interesting optimizations that could be performed on this whole-program-in-one-translation-unit code, and it is conceivable that one of them is responsible for `func1()`'s `n` parameter being dead.  What output does the program produce for you?

Comment: The call stack is from a debugger that I'm using. I do not know if optimization is being disabled because I don't have access to it.

Comment: What do you mean you "don't have access to it"?  Are you talking about the code you've presented in the question?  Surely you have control over how that's compiled.  We can only speak to what you actually present to us, and if that's not representative of the real problem, then your chances of getting useful help are slim.

Comment: FWIW, the code you presented compiles fine for me with gcc 4, produces plausible output when run, and gdb 7.2 backtraces of it do not exhibit any discernable weirdness analogous to that in the backtrace you presented, whether compiled with or without optimization.

Comment: I did not disable optimization in the sample code. But the call stack is representation of the actual code's call stack, I just changed the variables so it matches. As for the actual code I am unaware if optimization is disabled or not. The sample code and actual use different compilers, I'm trying to run the sample code through the same compiler as the actual code but for now this is all I can provide.

Comment: @John Bollinger So I can assume this is an issue of the compiler and not the code?

Comment: I'm sorry then.  If you cannot present anything with which we can reproduce the problem then your question is off-topic here.

Comment: I cannot say whether the actual problem is with compiler or code without examining code that at least adequately *models* the actual problem.  I doubt anyone else around here can do, either.  It seems likely, however, that both contribute.

Comment: Minor notes: although this is very unlikely to have anything to do with your bug, it’s a bad idea to assume that `int` is the same as `uint32_t` or that a function pointer is the same size as an object pointer (except on POSIX).  The portable way to print an int32_t is with `PRId32` from `<inttypes.h>` or `%ld` matching `(long)n`.  Function pointers might not be the same size as object pointers.  The only truly portable way to print a function pointer would be to convert the object representation to an array of `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 3):

Dead variables are variables that are written to, but never read again.  The compiler may optimize by removing this code since it won't affect the result, anyways.

Comment: @KeithThompson Rephrased.

Comment: Suggested tweak: the compiler *may* optimize by removing the code. (Deleting my previous comment.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Rephrased again.  Btw, OP should turn off optimization flags.  

That or declare `n` as `volatile`...so there's barely any chance of any optimization going on.  Then OP should probably not see `<< dead >> `.